# How to print a character above 0xFFFF?

Tags: c#, unicode, char

I wonder if it is possible to print a character above `0xFFFF` with Windows?

I am using Microsoft Visual Studio 2010 along with Windows XP. A character is 16 bits wide so codepoints greater than `0xFFFF` cannot really fit into a single char. Even when I try this:

```
int codepoint = char.ConvertToUtf32(charHS, charLS);
```

I will get the codepoint from the surrogate pair, but it still doesn't fit into a char.

If I paste a character from the higher multilingual planes into a string within C#, the string will have the length 2. If I try to print the string then I will print the two surrogate characters, which are not characters, E.G., have no codepoint by themselves, only as a pair, instead of the "real" character.

Shouldn't there be something like a 32-bit wide character that can hold codepoints higher than `0xFFFF`?

Comment: Are you trying to print to the console?

Comment: No, to some WinForms control (label, textbox etc.).

Answer (score 5):

> Shouldn't there be something like a 32 bit wide char that can hold codepoints higher than 0xFFFF?

Perhaps. But Windows support for outputting glyphs outside the base multilingual plane is based on UTF-16. Split into a high and low surrogate pair and pass as if it were two characters.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. How can i print it if i just have the surrogates. Surrogates are not characters, they do not have a codepoint except as a pair. And this codepoint is above 0xFFFF and doesn't fit into a single char of 16 bits.

Comment: You are confusing the *encoding* (UTF-16 with surrogate pairs) with the processing. Win32 understands, in a number of APIs, surrogate pairs and maps them to the applicable glyph. This is little different (in processing terms) to combining a code point with combining accents into a single glyph. One unit of the encoding does not mean a single unit of graphical output.

Comment: Thanks for your comment Richard. Yes you are right, i mean the processing. Can you tell what APIs understand the surrogate pairs?

Comment: @brighty You can try, or read [MSDN](http://msdn.com/library/) remembering to map the .NET operation to the Win32 API. In other words there is no definitive general statement as far as I am aware.